# Wordpress 500 Error

Tags: php, wordpress

İ have a wordpress site.

İ am click the category permalink or tag permalink server is showing 500 error

and error_log file created root directory

[18-Feb-2012 21:50:55 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/blabla/public_html/0/wp-content/themes/blabla/category.php on line 45

category.php file 45

```
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

My wordpress theme is gulsah.in/mini-star-minimal-wordpress-theme/

Please help

Comment: can you post the whole category.php?

Comment: We need the content of category.php file to fix this problem

Answer (score 1):

Delete 16. line:
`<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>`

Comment: İ am solved problem thanks for everything i am replace the postion <?php get_sidebar(); ?>  
<?php get_footer(); ?>  and problem solved

Comment: @KubaW How did you arrive at that conclusion?

Comment: I've looked at the template code: http://gulsah.in/mini-star-minimal-wordpress-theme/. There was a parser error, something like this (pseudocode): `<? if ($cond1): ... if ($cond1): ... endif; ?>`